# Docker на Window и macOS

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Пытаюсь создать новый Rails проект при помощи докера. Все получилось сделать на mac'е теперь хочу запустить тот же самый контейнер на Windows 10 получаю ошибку

```
D:\Projects\Docker\blog>docker-compose up -d 
blog_db_1 is up-to-date

Starting blog_api_1

ERROR: for api  Cannot start service api: mkdir /d: file exists

[31mERROR[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

D:\Projects\Docker\blog>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV HOME=/usr/src/app PATH=/usr/src/app/bin:$PATH
ADD Gemfile* /usr/src/app/
RUN set -ex && bundle install
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: s0m3p455
  api:
    build: .
    command: rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:s0m3p455@db:5432/my_app_development
```

Репозиторий со всем кодом (https://github.com/perevezencev/app)

Comment: добавьте в вопрос все необходимые файлы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: я не знаю будет ли достаточно Dockerfile и docker-compose.yml поэтому решил кинуть ссылку на репозиторий

Comment: ваш код не должен работать совсем. вы уверены, что на Mac OS он работал?

Comment: да =) запустилось и показало экран приветсвия

Comment: вот эта команда `COPY Gemfile* .` не может выполнится. проверяйте внимательно все ли вы скопировали как было. плюс без запуска **bundler** у вас не будет **rails**.

Comment: Еще раз попробовал создать все заново, взлетело (теперь точно). 
Теперь возникает следующая ошибка на windows 
`ERROR: for api  Cannot start service api: mkdir /d: file exists
[31mERROR[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

Comment: ну вы же все поменяли. Конечно ошибка в шла.

Comment: Да, поменял многое. Но ошибка осталась, не могу понять в чем дело

Comment: дело в вашей ОС. вот ссылка на баг https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25270